# Why does Makar Sankranti follow English calendar?

Tags: festivals

Why does Makar Sankranti always happens to be on Jan 14<sup>th</sup> / 15<sup>th</sup>, while all other Hindu festivals depend on size of moon like Chaturthi, Amavasya, Poornima etc.

Are there any more Hindu festivals which also follows English calendar?

Comment: Makar-Sankranti happens on every 14th January only.

Comment: @Kedarnath wikipedia says it mostly falls on 14 with some exceptions when the festival is celebrated on 13 or 15 January [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makar_Sankranti)

Comment: Other Hindu festival which apparently follows English calendar is Vishwakarma pooja, it is celebrated on 17th September every year.

Comment: But yes Makarsankranti have fallen on 13 or 15,
Actually it starts from 13 and end with 14 or starts on 14 and end on 15

Comment: @Kedarnath  fyi:  http://www.drikpanchang.com/sankranti/makar-sankranti-date-time.html?year=2015

Answer (score 9):

"Uttarayan", means the day on which sun moves towards "Uttar" means North direction.

We celebrate it only on 14<sup>th</sup>, the next day 15<sup>th</sup> is called "Vasee Uttarayan" means the following day of "Makar Sankranti" or "Stale Uttarayan".

It is considered that sun marching towards North takes souls to Heaven and heading towards south takes souls to hell. In Mahabharata it is mention when Bhishma decided to leave body on the day of Uttarayan only on the advice of Lord Krishna.

Hindu calendar is based on moon, but this day is related with sun. And as per Gregorian calendar this day is found that `the sun enters the Capricorn (Sanskrit: Makar) zodiac`, so Makar Sankranti is celebrated on this day only as it is solar event only.

> Hindu calendar is moon event based calendar and Gregorian Calendar is strictly a solar calendar based on solar events of 365 days.

As Makar Sankranti is solar event it is followed by Gregorian Calendar.

Answer (score 7):

A simple logic:

**Who gave English Calendar to Bhishma Pitamaha to leave his body on Makara Sankranti?**

Bhishma Pitamaha left his body on the day of Makara Sankranti. He wishfully remained alive up to the day of Makara Sankranti.

> The Mahabharata, Book 13: Anusasana Parva: Section CLXVII 
>   The Mighty Bhishma then, taking the strong hand of Yudhishthira, addressed him in a voice deep as that of the clouds. That thorough master of words said, 'By good luck, O son of Kunti, thou hast come here with all thy counsellors, O Yudhishthira! **The thousand-rayed maker of day, the holy Surya has begun his northward course.** 
>   I have been lying on my bed here for eight and fifty nights. Stretched on these sharp-
>   pointed arrows I have felt this period to be as long as if it was a century. O Yudhishthira, the lunar **month of Magha** has come.

Thus, Makara Sankranti is not by English Calendar. It falls when the Sun Enters the Capricorn (Makara) constellation. It usually happens in January 14th/15th but it doesn't mean that it is calculated by English Calendar. It isn't always necessary that Makara Sankranti falls in January 14th/15th.

Comment: @Vineet Suggest all the edits at once. Do not suggest edits to the answer twice or thrice. They are half-hearted edits. Please suggest all the edits all only once. Incomplete edits will be rejected.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma all right. From next time onward I will be more careful about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't necessarily comes on 14<sup>th</sup> January, We have seen it almost falls on 14 January many times it comes earlier or many times later.

> Hinduism is the major festivals of Makar Sankranti. This festival is
>   celebrated all over India in some form. Sun in Capricorn occurs on
>   Poush Mass is celebrated on the solstice.
>
> This festival is celebrated mostly on fourteen of January. Sometimes
>   the festival twelve, thirteen or fifteen may be, it depends on the
>   fact that when the sun enters Sagittarius Capricorn left. The day
>   begins with the sun's solstice speed and for this reason it is also
>   called Uttarayani.

Comment: Please edit this answer and explain in English of what you've written in Hindi or it would be better if you remove Hindi text if it isn't required at all. Failing to do so will lead me deleting your answer.

Comment: I think a person who can give resource from Sanskrit, can understand hindi as well.

Comment: @Keshav But there are people who can't understand either Sanskrit or Hindi, and the site is intended for them too.  It's an English-language site, so English speakers should be able to understand all questions and answers on this site.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I don't get time to translate.Please try to understand

Comment: @Keshav [It takes a second for me to translate](http://bit.ly/1vwASz6), also I delete such posts instantly but am providing you some extra time to do it and we are not talking about who is giving sources here. I don't understand Sanskrit and I take time to read Hindi so I prefer English instead, hope you understand. Apart from this, as I answered your meta question, people around the globe can neither read Sanskrit nor Hindi, so please use English in your answers next time(can use Hindi or Sanskrit for shlokas or similar snippets but also provide English translations for the same)

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not celebrated according to the English calendar.

From the point of view of *Jyotisha*, Makara Sankranti is celebrate ***when Surya (Sun) enters Makara Rashi (the zodiac named Capricorn).***

As, Jyotisha follows a *sidereal* (moveable) zodiac, these dates can change i.e. Surya can enter Makara on a different date. The question itself says that it can fall either on 14th or 15th.

The English calendar follows a *tropical* (fixed) zodiac, where they assume that Sun enters Capricorn on the same date every year which is not in sync with the facts (only an assumption).

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_and_tropical_astrology) article can be referred to learn more.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

We follow Moon Calendar as per that the Sankranti comes when Sun Enter Makar (Capricorn) which is also the start of Uttarayan.

The English Calendar based on Sun, therefore we find its always on 14th January. But as per Moon Calendar it keeps varies.... The Calendar which we follow now a days is Gregorian Calendar, which is based on Sun so its always fixed to 14th Jan.

For Sun based Calendar, Moon based festival keeps varies and vice as versa.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism! Can you kindly back your answer with authentic source?

Comment: Source: Makar sankranti [Srimad Bhagvatam](https://vanisource.org/wiki/SB_7.14.20-23?hl=Makara-sa%E1%B9%85kr%C4%81nti)
Vikram sanvat is a moon calendar  [Moon calendar] (https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/religion/festivals/vikram-samvat-hindu-new-year-history-legend-calculation-and-other-details/articleshow/82044253.cms)

Answer (score 1):

The Hindi Sanskrit text above translates to the following:

Hinduism is the major festivals of Makar Sankranti. This festival is celebrated all over India in some form. Sun in Capricorn occurs on Poush Mass is celebrated on the solstice.

This festival is celebrated mostly on fourteen of January. Sometimes the festival twelve, thirteen or fifteen may be, it depends on the fact that when the sun enters Sagittarius Capricorn left. The day begins with the sun's solstice speed and for this reason it is also called Uttarayani.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Hinduism SE. It is unclear what you are trying to answer here. Please add proper formatting and relevant details while answering